# RxJS Expand Reduce Loop not returning result

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to build up a list of paged results. I have the loop working but I can get the observable to emit the final result. It loops completes but never emits to the subscribe. Not sure if using EMPTY is the wrong way to finish, or if the reduce isn't hit because of the EMPTY and just never fires the last result?

```ts
getReportsAll(collection: Collection): Observable<PagedResult<ReportView>> {
return Observable.create(observer => {
  this.collectionService.collectionBy(collection)
  const url = this.collectionService.buildUrl(this.reportsUrl)
  const newPage = new PagedResult<ReportView>([], null, null, 0)
  this.getReportPage(url)
    .pipe(
      expand(result => {
        const skip = collection.pageBy.skip + collection.pageBy.top
        collection.pageBy = new PageBy(collection.pageBy.top, skip)
        this.collectionService.collectionBy(collection)
        const nextUrl = this.collectionService.buildUrl(this.reportsUrl)
        const test = result.count >= collection.pageBy.top ? this.getReportPage(nextUrl) : EMPTY
        console.log('test', test)
        return test
      }),
      reduce((next: PagedResult<ReportView>, data: PagedResult<ReportView>, index: number) => {
        next.value = [...next.value, ...data.value]
        next.count = next.value.length
        console.log('next', next, index)
        return next
      }, newPage),
    )
    // .catch(error => observer.error(error))
    .subscribe(results => {
      console.log('results', results)
    })
})
```

}

Comment: What is EMPTY constant here ?

Comment: Its the same as empty(), should fire a complete() on the observable:  https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/EMPTY

Answer (score 2):

I solved this I was missing takeWhile() here is the complete solution in case anyone else is wanting to do something similar.

```
  getReportsAll(collection: Collection): Observable<PagedResult<ReportView>> {
this.collectionService.collectionBy(collection)
const url = this.collectionService.buildUrl(this.reportsUrl)
const newPage = new PagedResult<ReportView>([], null, null, 0)
return this.getReportPage(url).pipe(
  expand(result => {
    const skip = collection.pageBy.skip + collection.pageBy.top
    collection.pageBy = new PageBy(collection.pageBy.top, skip)
    this.collectionService.collectionBy(collection)
    const nextUrl = this.collectionService.buildUrl(this.reportsUrl)

    return result.count >= collection.pageBy.top ? this.getReportPage(nextUrl) : of(null)
  }),
  takeWhile((value: PagedResult<ReportView> | Observable<void>, index: number) => {
    if (value === null) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  }),
  reduce((next: PagedResult<ReportView>, data: PagedResult<ReportView>, index: number) => {
    next.value = [...next.value, ...data.value]
    next.count = next.value.length
    return next
  }, newPage),
)
```

}

Comment: You have also removed that `Observable.create(observer => ....` which was pretty confusing

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't need it because I'm calling it somewhere else but its just a wrapper to create an observable

Comment: https://huantao.medium.com/rxjs-fetch-all-paginated-data-96500b73c120